# Angularjs selecting template for editing or dispaly depending on state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new to AngularJs. I got a list of objects which have a state.
Based on this state some of those objects are editable (say `state=1 or state=4`) or not `(state <> 1,4)`.
The link on the list should point to the editable or viewable version depending on the state.

I would like to understand a correct way to handle this.
Options:

1. different directives?
2. different templates ? Selectable how ?
3. `ng-if` in the same template?

In cases 1 and 2 how to better decide the editability? In the controller (at the price of a loop in the whole list of objects) or via a function in the html ?

For better I mean:

1. performance
2. app 'style'

Code Sample project-detail.component.js. Component recalled by the url #!/projects/:id

```
angular.module('projectDetail').
component('projectDetail', {
    templateUrl: 'app/project-detail/project-detail.template.html',
    controller:['$http','$routeParams', function ProjectDetailController($http,$routeParams) {
    var self=this;
    $http.get('rest/projects/' + $routeParams.id ).then(function(response) {
        self.project = response.data;

});
}
});
```

Code Sample edit-project-detail.component.js. Component recalled by the url #!/projects/edit/:id

```
angular.module('editProjectDetail').
component('editProjectDetail', {
    templateUrl: **'app/edit-project-detail/edit-project-detail.template.html',**
    controller:['$http','$routeParams', function EditProjectDetailController($http,$routeParams) {
    var self=this;
    $http.get('rest/projects/' + $routeParams.id ).then(function(response) {
        self.project = response.data;

});
}
});
```

HTML for call

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in $ctrl.projects track by project.id">
<td>{{project.id}}</td>
<td><a href="#!/projects/{{project.id}}">{{project.name}}</td>
<td>{{project.projectType}}</td>
<td>{{project.status.label}}</td>
...
</tr>
```

The 2 components are identical except for the template. I'm trying to understand if it is better to cycle on the whole array (may be long) in the list controller or put something like ng-if in the html or trying a way to select the correct template from the component declaration.

Comment: How do the links differ between versions?

Comment: The link may be something like project/edit/:1 for editing or project/:id for view.
The matter is that the components are absolutely equal. 
Both get data from the same service, and differ only in the fact that in one template we have forms and input, on the other not. That's why I'm wondering about the possibility of selecting different templates based on the status of the object, instead of different links. I'll put the example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct the link like:

```
<a href="somesite.com/{{ (state <> 1,4) ? 'edit' : 'view' }}/id={{obj.id}}"></a>
```

Assuming the links are like this: `somesite.com/edit/id=212` or `somesite.com/view/id=212`

EDIT to match your links

```
<a href="project/{{ (state <> 1,4) ? '' : 'edit' }}/:{{obj.id}}"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. My best would be instead to have the possibility of reuse the component code and having a good way to select the correct template. In fact the component (directive) is selected at route config and I don't have the possibility tu put the state attribute. Maybe an idea could be:
1. generate links as you suggest in the html
2. at route config put something like <project-detail edit='true'></project-detail> or <project-detail></project-detail> depending on the case

Comment: then make a controller function to construct the link and bind the function returning the link to the href

Comment: I'm worried this is considered a bad practice in terms of performance :(

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm no expert in angular

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't show any code, I assume you have a table that displays your objects. If this is true, to achieve what you want you should have something like:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in objects">
        <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
        <td ng-show="obj.state == 1 || obj.state == 4"><!-- edit link here --></td>
        <td ng-hide="obj.state == 1 || obj.state == 4"><!-- view link here --></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

No need for controllers or different templates, using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` should be enough for your needs.

Comment: I added the code and maybe clarified a little the question